# MySQL query with/without table specific reference

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

In Joomla 2.5.14, when I create a query to MySQL using PHP, like:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM xmb9d_content WHERE state=1" ;
```

It all works fine, but if I don't want a specific reference to the database prefix (xmb9d_) and use:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM #__content WHERE state=1" ;
```

The query isn't executed. Is this the right way of building the query or what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You're not showing how you execute the SQL query, that would be helpful, the "#__" is replaced by Joomla when you use Joomla's database methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the database prefix and also stick to Joomla 2.5 coding standards. There shouldn't be any problems with the prefix, providing your query is correct.

This is how it should look:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('id')
 ->from('#__content')
 ->where('state = 1');

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea: to comply with J2.5 standards, keep the code clean and easy to maintain although I'm not at all familiar with it yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is good documentation for Joomla now. Have a look around on there and on Stackoverflow to find good examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

`xmb9d_content` is the name of the table by replacing it with `#__content` you are attempting to run the query on a table that doesn't exist (i assume) so it wont work.

What is the issue with the prefix? I don't understand how it could cause you an problems

Comment: This is a Joomla-specific notation. `#__` is automatically replaced by a predefined table prefix which allows several installations to use the same DB, with different prefixes.